# CDATA not rendering tags

Tags: html, python

I'm trying to display XML tags mixed in with plain text on a web page.  I do this from a python script that obtains it's data from a database.  I've simplified my problem to the program below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
print """Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n"""
print """<html><body>
start:<![CDATA[This is the <xml> tag </xml>.]]>:end
</body></html>"""
```

I'm expecting it to display the following:

```
start:This is the <xml> tag </xml>.:end
```

In both IE8 and Chrome15 it however displays the following:

```
start: tag .]]>:end
```

When I look at the HTML source of the page in IE, I can see the following:

```
<html><body>
start:<![CDATA[This is the <xml> tagxml.]]>:end
</body></html>
```

In Chrome I see the the same when looking at the source, but it seems that the `<![CDATA[This is the <xml>` part is in green because it is considered a comment.

I particularly want to keep the text (instead of converting the `<` to `&lt;`) because via javascript I access the elements, allowing people to edit them in a separate textarea.  Converting them would then save them converted, resulting in problems further down in processing.  I could convert them back before saving, but this seems like the wrong approach.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Grant

Answer (score 1):

CDATA is part of XML, not HTML, so the browser ignores it, and then treats any tags in it as it would any other tags - ignoring ones it doesn't recognise, and paying attention to those it does.

I think there's no alternative but to use `&lt;` etc and convert to tags when editing and convert back when saving.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to give it a try I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;</div>
        <textarea id="area"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
            var area = document.getElementById('area')
            var text = div1.firstChild.nodeValue
            area.value = text
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where the problem is?

Comment: Thanks.  I gave this a try and it seemed to work at first.  I however used innerHTML instead of firstChild.nodeValue as there might be multiple text nodes (within my td).  innerHTML does not seem to work, but innerTEXT does (even though I'm not sure how widely it is supported).

Comment: @grantstead innerText is an old IE property, but there is standart one - textContent, so `e.textContent || e.innerText || ''`.